# What is an alternate method to flash stock firmware for S9+ G965F?

Tags: twrp, boot-loop, device-firmware, odin, samsung-galaxy-s-9

My S9+ went into bootloop, I loaded up twrp through odin and flashed no-verity-opt-encrypt-samsung-1.0.zip

The problem is when phone turns off, it goes back into bootloop. I tried flashing stock firmware through odin, but odin crashes whenever I load up AP. I tried different versions on 2 computers but no luck.

What is an alternate to the stock firmware that I can flash to stop the bootloop?

Comment: Odin crashes? How?

Comment: Yes, it never happened before but that one AP file makes odin crash everytime :/                (AP_G965FXXU8DTC5_CL18339721_QB30180704_REV01_user_low_ship_meta_OS10.tar.md5)